# jquery ajax call with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

i have a problem with the ajax call.
here's my code:

```
$.ajax({ 
            url : "my_controller/jsonSubcategories/"+$(this).attr('id')+"",
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function( data ) {

                })
            },
            error:function( result ){ console.log(["error", result]) }
        });
```

and my_controller code:

```
public function jsonSubcategories($idParent){
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($this->Term->get_terms_byParent('subcategory',$idParent));

}
```

the call give me error!

if i manually go for example to my_controller/jsonSubCategories/5 it doesnt show me only the json encoded object but also part of my hooks yield layout.
the problem is caused by  the layout? in that case is possible to exclude the layout hooks for the ajax call?

Comment: what happens if you use `die(json_encode(...));` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure when the "hooks yield layout" is, but yeah, it is easy to exclude that for your ajax request.

Just put a `GET` parameter such as `format=json` after your request URL:

```
$.ajax({ 
        url : "my_controller/jsonSubcategories/"+$(this).attr('id')+"?format=json",
```

And in your `hooks` file, somewhere in the beginning of the function that is being executed, add the following:

```
if ($_GET['format'] === 'json') return;
```

This should pretty much solve the problem.

Specifying your output format via the `GET` parameter is a common way of controlling different outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. I have not tested the following code, but I think it should work.

```
public function jsonSubcategories($idParent){
    ob_get_clean();
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($this->Term->get_terms_byParent('subcategory',$idParent));
}
```

Basically whatever had been echo'ed so far, if output buffering was not disabled in your php.ini, is stored in a buffer and this buffer is cleared by the ob_get_clean call, and you can rest assured that no content will be echoed before your json content. Additional thing to check would be to see if your hooks call ob_start again as that would mean you will have to ob_get_clean until all of the buffers stack is popped empty.